# Prevent user of changing variable type in python

Tags: python, built-in

I have main class with a lot of attributes that are initially defined as an object of a `Prop` class. This `Prop` class has two attributes: its `value` and the `options`, which is a list of acceptable values for the attribute.

```
class Prop():
    def __init__(self, value, *options):
        self.value = value
        self.options = options

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop1 = Prop(None)
        self._prop2 = Prop(None)
```

The first important thing here is that `_propx` has to be an instance variable, since I will create more than one instance of Main.

The values of a `Prop` instance can either be a string or an integer, but the problem with this code is that I have to be sure that the user will do something like `main._prop1.value = 1` and not `main._prop1 = 1` otherwise it would break my code when doing `_prop1.options`. I don't want to use traits, thus I decided to make each `_propx` instance a kind of `property`, but I'm talking about a lot of instances and I don't want to define each setter especially because they will be all the same.

I found two solutions to solve this problem, the first is by using the same setter to all properties:

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop1 = Prop(None)
        self._prop2 = Prop(None)

    def set_prop(attr):
        def set_value(self, value):
            self.__dict__[attr].value = value
        return set_value

    prop1 = property(fset=set_prop('_prop1'))
    prop2 = property(fset=set_prop('_prop2'))
```

The second is by using an auxiliary class and redefine its `__set__`:

```
class Aux():
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print(self, obj, value, self.private_name)
        obj.__dict__[self.private_name].value = value

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop1 = Prop(None)
        self._prop2 = Prop(None)

    prop1 = Aux()
    prop2 = Aux()
```

the first on seems cleaner, but I have to pass the private name of each variable and I have to write the setter in the `Main` which I don't like because I would it to be as clean as possible. By other hand, in the second I have to use an auxiliary class.

My question is: is there a way of defining the setter in the `Prop` class? The reason why I couldn't find a way of doing this is that the `Aux.__set__` seems to work only when I create an Aux instance as a class variable (static variable). This is also why I have to create a private and a public variable for each property. Is there a way of using `__set__` to an instance (non-static) variable?

Comment: Both your solutions look fine, and I don't really understand the problem here. Maybe you could narrow it down to what you want to know beyond these two solutions?

Comment: `Aux` is a descriptor. The descriptor protocol is only invoked for objects in the class namespace. This is how it's meant to be used. You *could* just write a regular setter... fo course, then you are simply creating a class variable, the method, which will manipulate an instance variable... exactly like your `Aux` class...

Comment: "By other hand, in the second I have to use an auxiliary class." I mean, so what?

Comment: Is there no way I can define a setter directly to the Prop class so I don't have to do prop1=Aux(), prop2=Aux(), prop3=Aux() ... I have tried but it didn't work because it was not being called

Comment: @FlavioMoraes what do you mean by "a setter"? You can, of course, define a `def set_prop1(self, val)` function in `Main`. If you are referring to `__set__`, as I explained already, that is part of the *descriptor protocol*, descriptors have to be class objects, not instance objects for the descriptor protocol to be invoked

Comment: and is there an equivalent of `__set__` to instance objects?

Comment: @FlavioMoraes If I understand correctly, you want to do `main.prop1 = Prop()` and then later, when `main.prop1 = 'foo'` then the `Prop` instance should detect that it's been overridden? If so, that's impossible. It's up to `Main` to decide what happens (possibly delegating via descriptors, as you showed in your question).

Comment: thank you all. @a_guest that was what I was looking for. But if this is impossible I will leave it the way I did